# Asp.net mvc authenticate with google plus

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth

I have create an application to authenticate with Google plus but I don't want all Gmail users to access my application but only the users in my domain which I bought from Google my domain is (`example.net`) and all emails will be (`email@example.net`).

Comment: Don't you able to check if user belongs to your domain or not?

Comment: I can do it from the c# but I want to do from google side

Answer (score 0):

You could validate user email when user registers and reject to register if the email is not the one you want. You can do so in AccountController.Register action by validating the specified email, and not creating user if email does not come from your domain.

Google OAuth provider returns user email, if you ask it to do it (add scope "email" to GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions in Startup.Auth)

```
googleAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
```

You can ensure that the email is coming from Google by making the field "Email" in "ExternalLoginConfirmation" view read-only (or hidden).